# How to pass non-form data in a custom form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have a form where I pass related data like this:

```
form_for(@question, url: create_question_path(category_id: @category.id)) do |f|
  f.text_field :content
  submit_tag "Save"
save
```

How do I get the `category_id` on the same nested level as `content`, so as [strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) evaluates it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can include it as a tag and if i understand you correctly you want it hidden so:

```
hidden_field_tag 'category_id', @category.id
```

now it will be submitted as params[:category_id] and not params[:questions][:category_id] to solve it in your controller create `before_filter`:

```
def prepare_params      
  params[:question][:category_id] = params[:category_id]
  params.delete :category_id
end
```